# Boolean (BitArray) multidimensional array indexing or masking in Julia?

Tags: multidimensional-array, julia, bitmask, bitarray

As part of a larger algorithm, I need to produce the residuals of an array relative to a specified limit. In other words, I need to produce an array which, given `someArray`, comprises elements which encode the amount by which the corresponding element of `someArray` exceeds a limit value. My initial inclination was to use a distributed comparison to determine when a value has exceeded the threshold. As follows:

```
# Generate some test data.
residualLimit = 1
someArray = 2.1.*(rand(10,10,3).-0.5)

# Determine the residuals.
someArrayResiduals = (residualLimit-someArray)[(residualLimit-someArray.<0)]
```

The problem is that the `someArrayResiduals` is a one-dimensional vector containing the residual values, rather than a mask of `(residualLimit-someArray)`. If you check `[(residualLimit-someArray.<0)]` you'll find that it is behaving as expected; it's producing a `BitArray`. The question is, why doesn't Julia allow to use this `BitArray` to mask `someArray`?

Casting the `Bools` in the `BitArray` to `Ints` using `int()` and distributing using `.*`produces the desired result, but is a bit inelegant... See the following:

```
# Generate some test data.
residualLimit = 1
someArray = 2.1.*(rand(10,10,3).-0.5)

# Determine the residuals.
someArrayResiduals = (residualLimit-someArray).*int(residualLimit-someArray.<0)

# This array should be (and is) limited at residualLimit. This is correct...
someArrayLimited = someArray + someArrayResiduals
```

Anyone know why a `BitArray` can't be used to mask an array? Or, any way that this entire process can be simplified?

Thanks, all!

Comment: check this syntax: `(residualLimit-someArray).*(residualLimit-someArray.<0)`

Comment: how about: `max(someArray-residualLimit,0)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indexing with a logical array simply *selects* the elements at indices where the logical array is true.  You can think of it as [transforming the logical index array with `find` before doing the indexing expression](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/arrays/#indexing).  Note that this can be used in both array indexing and indexed assignment.  These logical arrays are often themselves called masks, but indexing is more like a "selection" operation than a clamping operation.

The suggestions in the comments are good, but you can also solve your problem using logical indexing with indexed assignment:

```
overLimitMask = someArray .> residualLimit
someArray[overLimitMask] = residualLimit
```

In this case, though, I think the most readable way to solve this problem is with `min` or `clamp`: `min(someArray, residualLimit)` or `clamp(someArray, -residualLimit, residualLimit)`

Comment: Wonderful answer. Thanks! I ended up using a `clamp`-based solution, as it was much easier to follow.